# AMD ATI Radeon HD R7750 support ATI Stream?

Tags: streaming, amd-radeon, backtrack

I am thinking to purchase a graphic card and do not have much budget to spend on it?. However I do like the AMD ATI Radeon HD R7750 and it is well in budget. But I would like to know if it supports ATI Stream to perform on BackTrack 5 r3.

Any guidance on this topic would be much appreciated.